# How can I get at the Email address of a Contact Reference? CiviMail and Tokens question!

Tags: civimail, tokens

It's straight forward to insert the Name of a Contact Reference (custom field) in CiviMail using Tokens. Does anyone know of a way to get at the Email address belonging to that Contact Reference?

Comment: I started writing an Extension so if you have the answer don’t delay 

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the "[Related Token Extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/related-tokens)" does the trick? Even if not, it may be better to build up on an existing extension that pulls token from related contacts instead of building a new extension from the scratch.

Another example for such an extension ist the "[Additional Token](https://github.com/systopia/de.systopia.stoken)" extension, I am pretty sure I have seen others...

Comment: Hi Fabian - Like the Fuzion token extension Related Token extension only handles relationships. I ended up writing a small custom extension yesterday.